# Monitor - how to stop at last plot

Tags: monitoring

I am using ListPlot to plot some data, the corresponding function is named showListPlot.
Now I would like to show a series of such plots in the same window. To do that I am using the following:

```
Monitor[For[index = 1, index < number + 1, index++, 
  s = showListPlot[index]] , s]
```

I would like that monitor stops at the last plot (to see the end state) and does not vanish. How is that possible?

Comment: You might consider whether `Animate` and `ListAnimate` are possible alternative approaches.  `For` loops are unnecessary and are included in *Mathematica*, IMO, to make it easy to translate C/Fortran code.  If such a loop is needed in your actual application, consider `Do`.

Comment: I combined you hint with kgulers code, which is also nice:

lp = ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}] & /@ 
   RandomReal[10, {10, 50}];
showlp = Show[lp[[#]], 
    PlotLabel -> Style["index = " <> ToString@#, 16, Bold]] &;
number = Length[lp];

ListAnimate[Table[showlp[index], {index, 1, number}], 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lp = ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}] & /@ RandomReal[10, {10, 50}];
showlp = Show[lp[[#]], PlotLabel -> Style["index = " <> ToString@#, 16, Bold]] &;
number = Length[lp];
```

**Update:** If you don't **have to** use `Monitor`, there are a number of alternatives including `Dynamic` and `Clock` combination:

```
Dynamic@With[{c = Clock[{1, number, 1}, 5, 1]}, showlp[c]]
```

[image]

**Original post:**

```
Monitor[For[index = 1, index < number, Pause[.3]; index++, s = showlp[index]], s]; showlp[number]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kguler. I have the impression that this routine is showing the last plot twice?

Comment: @MilenkoRubin-Zuzic, you are right. If that is an issue, you can change `number+1` to `number` and `s` at the end to `showlp[number]`.

Comment: That's it. Why so easy ... can you change the upper code , so that I can vote for the answer?

Comment: @Milenko, just updated the answer.

Comment: Michael E2 had the idea tu use ListAnimate. So we could also could replace the line with Monitor[] ... to:
ListAnimate[Table[showlp[index], {index, 1, number}], 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1]. Also nice ...

Answer (score 1):

```
showListPlot[index_] := {Plot[x, {x, 0, 3}], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}], Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 3}]}[[index]]

number = 3;

Block[{printFunction = PrintTemporary}, 
    Do[If[index == number, printFunction = Print]; 
        printFunction[showListPlot[index]]; Pause[1]
    , {index, number}]
]
```

Monitor is still better I guess, but here it goes the edit:

```
showListPlot[index_] := {Plot[x, {x, 0, 3}], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}], Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 3}]}[[index]]

number = 3;

PrintAndDelete[expression_]:=Module[{cell},cell=PrintTemporary[expression];Pause[1];NotebookDelete[cell]]

Module[{printFunction=PrintAndDelete},
    Do[If[index==number,printFunction=Print];printFunction[showListPlot[index]],{index, number}]
]
```

Comment: Dear Giovanni, I would like to see the curves in the "same window cell" and that the last plot is not cleared.

Comment: Dear Giovanni, interesting ... I did not know this ... thanks